# Uploading file on ASP.NET MVC site (not uploading)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have set up an upload file feature on my asp.net mvc site.  The code doesn't throw any errors but the file I select to upload, doesn't get stored in the specified location. Below is my code.

Controller

```
public ActionResult uploadCourseList(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

            var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), filename);
            file.SaveAs(path);

            KuPlanEntities db = new KuPlanEntities();

            var user = "000000001";

            var userIdvar = (from userId in db.AspNetUsers
                             where userId.Id == user
                             select userId.Id).ToString();

            var stuList = (from users in db.AspNetUsers
                           where users.advisor == user
                           select new listStudentViewModel { Id = users.Id, fname = users.fname, lname = users.lname });

        return View("~/Views/ManageStudentCourses/Index.cshtml", stuList);
    }
```

View

```
 <div id="uploadCourseList">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("uploadCourseList", "ManageStudentCourses", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <table class="courseListTable">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4">
                        Upload Course List
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Select a file:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: I think it's because you're uploading to the /App_Data folder which is (normally) not accessible from the client. I would create a different directory that's specific for uploads.

Comment: Your code is working absolutely fine for me. Can you debug your code and see what is there in `file` variable.